# Is it possible for humanity to face extinction at the hands of a pandemic?

Tags: biology, diseases, health, extinction

Over the course of history, humanity has faced a number of epidemics, some have even lead to the mass death of many people throughout the world. Surely though we are advanced enough to cope with outbreaks? Surely they can only occur in impoverished countries with limited health care infrastructure? This was the case with the most recent Ebola outbreak in west Africa? 
However, with the rise superbugs like MRSA, one must pose the question whether a disease could, in fact, wipe us out? Admittedly I take inspiration from the media with games such as Plague inc. But I am genuinely curious as to what the possible extent of an outbreak could be in its worse case scenario.

Please keep responses limited to modern day technologies and economies. Also, I am new here and I realise my question may be a little too broad but I'm not sure how to make it less so. Anyway- I've looked at previous similar topics and this specific question hasn't yet been posed in this way- to my knowledge, thanks.

Comment: Modern day global society is even more vulnerable because diseases spread that much easier by things like airplanes, easily breaching ocean barriers.

Comment: Not as long as President Madagascar keeps shutting down everything.